# Unable to install ROS turtlesim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
After installing the ROS, i was going through the tutorials to learn it

[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages)
At this page when i tried to navigate to the turtlesim using roscd turtlesim, it threw an error *roscd: No such package/stack 'turtlesim'*

so, going through another post, [link text](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=48676&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20) ,
i got to know that i am supposed to run *sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-ros-tutorials*.
but once i ran this, i again got an error *E: Unable to locate package ros-cturtle-ros-tutorials*
Since i am newbie, could you please explain me clearly, on how to proceed on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46227/unable-to-install-ros-turtlesim/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2012-10-18**:
Thanks a lot for replying.
are you saying that ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set up at all or did u mean that i need to include something else to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable?
Because when i typed the *echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH*, i got something like
*/home/mhariharasudan/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-18**:
Please provide all relevant information including the version of your operating system and the ROS distro you are using. See http://ros.org/wiki/Support Did you maybe install fuerte? Then install turtlesim with: `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ros-tutorials`. Also, your package path is wrong.

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2012-10-18**:
Thanks a lot, that worked. Yea i had installed Fuerte. And in the previous comment the whole package path was not pasted. The package path is */home/mhariharasudan/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros* Is this one correct or should i change?

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2012-10-18**:
Thanks a lot, that worked. Yea

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2012-10-18**:
Thanks a lot, that worked. Yea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure about the ubuntu packages, but the first part of your error sounds like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable has not been setup.  This environment variable includes all the paths of your different packages and is what the roscd command uses to find them.  Check through the tutorials (maybe a non-ubuntu one?) and it will detail how to setup your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) with karma: 506 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-18**:
Relevant link on setting up ROS_PACKAGE_PATH correctly: http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays